# PHP Displaying POST data to another page to display

Tags: php, redirect, curl, post

I currently have a program that will run tests on a server and it will send the results to the test.php file. I am trying to redirect my POST data to reports.php page, this data is in JSON format and I want to display the data on the page in reports.php nicely (eventually). The data comes in slowly, and I am able to see the data in https://requestb.in/ when I change the URL in my `test.php` to the one given in the requestb.in. I know in my `test.php` everything I curl from `reports.php` it will just echo back into `test.php` Currently, when I open the report.php I get a blank white page after data has been sent. I need to do something just like how the requestb.in handles the incoming data and displays it, how can I do this?

test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// turn on error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//URL to POST JSON data to
$url = "http://my/dir/to/reports.php"; //if changed to requestb.in URL then i can see correct data

$post_data = array(
  'id' => $argv[1],
  'version' => $argv[2],
  'server' => $argv[3],
  'status' => $argv[4],
  'test' => $argv[5],
  'time' => $argv[6],
  'body' => $argv[7],
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "success: \n\n";
    print_r($result);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

reports.php

```
<?php  //reports.php
//This php file is to receive the POST data coming from php files.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    print_r($_POST);
} 
?>
```

Comment: So you are saying you are loading reports.php after firing the curl request, and expecting data to be there?

Comment: Did you tried to dump $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']?This should not contain 'POST' value because you use redirect.

Comment: @MrMarlow No i am not expecting data to be there, because i know data is still coming in, but even after waiting for the data to finish processing and refreshing the page, i still dont see any data on the page.

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko No i haven't tried that yet, let me try that right now and see if it works.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour yes, try it, now I am almost sure that it is a problem

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko So are you saying something like this?                              
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko Yeah, that didn't work. It seems like it just returns everything back to the echo.  i need to somehow intercept the data.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour yes, I think this should contain 'GET'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158124/discussion-between-dmitriy-buteiko-and-kkmoslehpour).

Comment: Use Ajax to pull the data.